# woocommerce product grid breaking

Tags: woocommerce

I have this shop https://ergonomus.co/tienda/
and as you can see, the grid breaks.

It must be a css related issue, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it adding

```css
/* Flexbox on WooCommerce archive products */
.woocommerce .products ul,
.woocommerce ul.products {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.product,
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.product .button {
 margin-top: auto;
 display: table;
}
```

but still the grid has a blank margin on the right....i dont get it